# forEach method combined with object.assign

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach

```
const prices = {
    ["Doll", "3.45"],
    ["Car", "4.75"],
    ["Teddybear", "5.45"],  
};

const newPrices = {};
prices.forEach((obj => object.Assign(obj,{name:value};
    console.log(newPrices));
```

// this should be the output:
newPrices = {[Doll:3.45],[Car:4.75],[Teddybear:5.45]};

Comment: The output you desire isn't valid JS. Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for this:

```js
const prices = [
    ["Doll", "3.45"],
    ["Car", "4.75"],
    ["Teddybear", "5.45"],  
];

const newPrices = Object.fromEntries(prices);
```

[Here's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) some more information about the `Object.fromEntries` method.

If you are working on a personal exercise to practice using the `forEach` and `Object.assign` methods, here's how that approach would look:

```js
const prices = [
    ["Doll", "3.45"],
    ["Car", "4.75"],
    ["Teddybear", "5.45"],  
];

const newPrices = {};
prices.forEach(([key, value]) => Object.assign(newPrices, { [key]: value }));
```

Comment: Heyyy, thanks for answering!!! But i need a forEach method inside the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your data model is wrong. I am not completely sure what you are trying to achieve.

```
const prices = [
  { name: 'Doll', price: '3.45' },
  { name: 'Car', price: '4.75' },
  { name: 'Teddybear', price: '5.45' },
];

prices.forEach((price) => {
  console.log(price.name, price.price);
});
```